# Control template for ListViewItem - how to access property of item

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

**Solved:**
I was an idiot and trusted the editors information that the DataContext is wrong. The solution is simply

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" />
```

---

I added a TextBlock beneath each displayed Item of a ListView. For this I used a ControlTemplate with the target type set to "ListViewItem". I put the GridViewRowPresenter and the TextBlock into a StackPanel.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

   <ListView.Resources>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomListViewItemTemplate" TargetType='{x:Type ListViewItem}'>
         <StackPanel>
            <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" /> <!-- here I fail -->
         </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </ListView.Resources>

   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomListViewItemTemplate}"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

   <ListView.View>
      <GridView> 
            ... 
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>

</ListView>
```

The ItemsSource of the ListView is a ObservableCollection `Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();`
with Item as

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
```

I can access the ListViewItem in the ControlTemplate, but not the Item itself. Is there a possibility bind the TextBlock in the ControlTemplate to e.g. the Property "A" of each instance of Item?

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" /> ` should work, because Item is DataContext of ListViewItem

Comment: It's just `Text="{Binding A}"`. Note however that by using this Template you loose all the features of the default Template, i.e. visualization of mouse over, selection and focus state.

Comment: It works. Thanks! ...damn I feel ashamed now. After weeks of developing WPF stuff, I made the mistake and trusted the tooltip information "cannot resolve property in data context ... " in the editor . Don't know why I did not simply press "build and run" once with this exact binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">` you specify which collection (In this case `Items`) provides data for the ListView. Within the template, if you assign the value `"{Binding}"`, you effectively assign an Item from your collection you specified as ItemsSource. 
To assign a binding to a property of your Item, you already found the solution

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding A}"/>
```

Additionally to your current solution,

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=A, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

above syntax allows you to navigate to nested members, and set additional binding related parameters like Mode, UpdateSourceTrigger, Converter etc.